# Using $http in Angular Service - Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm trying to learn how to use Angular right, by having all my business logic in services.

When I do a post request in a service, I get the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
```

Here is some code:

```
      UrlApp.controller('UrlFormCtrl', UrlFormCtrl);

      UrlApp.factory('addUrlService', addUrlService);

      function UrlFormCtrl($scope, $http) {
        console.log('Url Form Controller Initialized');
        $scope.addUrl = addUrlService.bind(null, $http);
      }

      function addUrlService($scope, $http){
        console.log('initializing addUrlService');
        return $http.post('urls/create', {'test':'test'}).then(function(response){
          return response.data;
        });
      }
```

I'm just getting the hang of Angular, so I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong. See any problems?

Comment: you could add **dependency-injection** (or di) to the question tags since IMO it is relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need to inject `$scope` in your service.

Secondly, you don't need to inject `$http` service in your controller.

Thirdly, you need to inject the service in your controller.

Finally, `addUrlService` service is returning a promise meaning **it will make a request when service is instantiated**. You may want to return a function instead or an object containing several functions.

So I would change your code to:

```
UrlApp.controller('UrlFormCtrl', UrlFormCtrl);
UrlApp.factory('AddUrlService', AddUrlService);

function UrlFormCtrl($scope, AddUrlService) {
    $scope.addUrl = AddUrlService.addUrl;
}

function AddUrlService($http) {

    function addUrl() {
        return $http.post('urls/create', {
            'test': 'test'
        }).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    }

    return {
        addUrl: addUrl
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, should a service be used for one controller or multiple? Let's say I have one controller that deals with a form and another to list in a table. Would it be suitable to use a all around UrlService instead or use two?

Comment: @kinx you should make services reusable when possible. Services in angular work as singletons in the application so when I want a service to be used by several modules in my application, I make it stateless.
I don't know your application, but this service could be a generic `UrlService` (instead of `AddUrlService`), that is a **CRUD** to manage urls in some database. Therefore, it could be used by any controller, service, whatever.

Comment: Thanks, @letiagoalves, one last question: The last return statement, I get that it's returning a json object, however, what you're doing here: addUrl:addUrl is really confusing me, cause you're just repeating it twice. Mind explaining it?

Comment: @kinx you are right. it is returning a literal `Object`. And that object has one property called `addUrl` that references the function `addUrl`. I gave the same name for the function and for the object property but you don't need to. If you want you can change the function name and the property name. For example: `add: addUrl`. But don't forget to change also in the controller if you change the property name.

Comment: Hi, it seems that this runs on page load when I need the service to run after a ng-click.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Can you try like this

 UrlApp.controller('UrlFormCtrl', UrlFormCtrl); 
 UrlApp.factory('addUrlService', addUrlService);

  function UrlFormCtrl($scope,addUrlService) {
    console.log('Url Form Controller Initialized');
    $scope.addUrl = addUrlService;
  }

  function addUrlService($http){
    console.log('initializing addUrlService');
    return $http.post('urls/create', {'test':'test'}).then(function(response){
      return response.data;
    });
  }
```